# After start php script and successful implementation, server send all request 504 error

Tags: php, apache2, nginx, vps, http-status-code-504

After 504 error, the problem is corrected only reboot. Server = vps. Here is the script followed by error:

```
<?php

$data = array('url','url','url'...'url');
foreach($data AS $v) {
  shell_exec('wget -O /dev/null '.$v);
}
```

'url' about a hundred, all of them successfully performed, URL is service on the same VPS only on a different port (handled by the script into perl, nginx is not involved). On the server, nginx, followed by apache2.

If the call does not foreach, but just once a team is all about. I tried to add 0.2 seconds usleep between calls to no avail. At first it was just a file_get_contents, then transcribed by fsockopen, then on wget.

Help out where to look. Logs look, there's nothing

Answer (score 0):

You can try by creating a shell script (bash?) that does the job and make PHP only fill in a txt file that will serve as source for the script to be run, so you can call the shell_exec() from PHP only once and achieve the same result...

Comment: I try this code:
$cmd = '';
foreach ($data AS $v) {
 $cmd .= ' "'.$v.'"';
}
shell_exec('wget -O /dev/null'.$cmd);
And server again send error 504

Answer (score 0):

Use need two things, first - in your php script add next settings:

```
<?php
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);
...
```

in NGINX you should add:

## 15 minutes

```
proxy_pass http://apache_server:80;
....
proxy_read_timeout 900s;
proxy_send_timeout 900s;
```

This should works fine. If none - try to increase limit.

Comment: My script work good. It send response and status 200. All urls call my script work done. After all call server send 504 to all request. Also <?php echo '1';

Comment: May be problem in shell_exec, try to replace it with file_get_contents for example